# What does mean OP?

Tags: meaning, abbreviations

I came across with OP in some sentences like this: Your answer doesn't relate to the OP's question ...

It obviously refers to the "person" who has asked the "original question", and they(O & P) must be the shortened form of two words or a phrase. Could you please tell me which words(or phrase) are meant by OP?

Comment: Related EL&U question [Does OP mean “original poster” or “original post”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/424366/80039)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**OP** is a shortened form of '**original poster**'. The original poster is the person who begins an online discussion and during the discussion others can refer to “original poster” with this abbreviation in order to saving time. Also(as LawrenceC remarked) it means "**original post**" referring to the post itself.

OP has an other meaning as 'overpowered' in the area of online gaming, but it doesn’t relate to your question.

Comment: Can also mean "original post" referring to the post itself.