# What does "used to" mean in the definition part in a dictionary?

Tags: word-meaning, american-english, british-english, spoken-english

I modified the original question to make it clearer so that it could help more people. If you want to see the original question, please see the edit history or scroll down.

--
I'm using the Longman dictionary to look up the word ***come on***. The definition of it is

> ***used to** tell someone to hurry or try harder*. [source](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/come-on)

Does it mean that people used ***come on*** in the past but do not use it nowadays? Because **used to** means ***something happened regularly or all the time in the past, but does not happen now***

--

----- original question ----
**original title**: How do people say "come on" in modern life 
**original body**: 
I thought that "come on" meant to tell somebody to hurry or try harder.
However, when I look up "come on" in the dictionary today, it says

**come on** 
used to tell someone to hurry or try harder

Source: [Longman Dic](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/come-on)

I wonder how people express "hurry up" or "try harder" in modern daily life.

Do you say "come on" in your daily life

---

update:
I also checked "used to". It means: "if something used to happen, it happened regularly or all the time in the past, but does not happen now".
so isn't the meaning "used to tell someone..." means that people say "come on" in the past, but does not happen now?

Comment: You thought saying 'come on' meant to tell somebody to hurry or try harder. Then you looked in a dictionary, and found that is exactly the meaning. So what is your question?

Comment: If your question is 'Do people say 'Come on!' in modern life, the answer is 'Yes, they do.'

Comment: I also checked "used to". It means :"if something used to happen, it happened regularly or all the time in the past, but does not happen now". 
so isn't the meaning "used to tell..." means that people say "come on" in the past, but does not happen now?

Comment: This is a different usage. Dictionaries often use shortened forms in definitions. The dictionary is saying 'Come on!' **is** used **in speech** to tell someone to hurry up or try harder.

Comment: Note that ***Come on!*** is often used with the saame meaning as ***Come off it!*** *(I utterly reject what you're saying)*. But imperative ***Come along!*** almost always means ***Hurry up!*** or ***Get moving!*** or similar.

Comment: I got it! Thanks for your patient reply.

Comment: If it was an expression that isn't used any more, the dictionary would have said **dated** (old-fashioned, unfamiliar to younger people) or **archaic** (only found in literature from several centuries ago).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OP isn't *really* asking for "synonyms for **Come on!**" - or at least, he *shouldn't be*.

OP's question has only arisen because he misunderstands ***used to*** in the cited dictionary definition.

It's ***used = made use of*** (pronounced to rhyme with ***mused, cruised, boozed,...***). This is *not* the same as idiomatic ***used to = habitually did** [in the past]* (pronounced to rhyme with ***boost, roost,...***).

In short, the dictionary is *not* suggesting that ***Come on!*** is no longer in use. It's just explaining how it ***is*** used.

Comment: Why do you and a few others refuse to put a the before OP? Sounds like a legal text: Plaintiff claimed [blah blah  blah]. No the just sounds so odd.

Comment: Each to their own, I suppose. In this particular case, the first OP (*with* article) is intended to refer [*Original **Post***](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/168926/126), and the next one (*without* article) refers to the person who *made* that post. But it's of no consequence if other people recognize that distinction or not - they could even assign the precisely *opposite* senses without affecting overall compehension of my text. And I don't suppose many non-native speakers know English well enough to even understand your point, let alone recognize it unaided, and feel "slighted".

Comment: The question has changed rather a lot. The original question literally asked for different ways of saying "come on" or "try harder".
The revised question is COMPLETELY different. I answered the initial version.

Comment: Arguably you should have waited or asked for clarification. But it looked pretty obvious to me right from the first version of the OP that it was predicated on misparsing of the cited dictionary definition.

Answer (score -2):

- Pull your socks up. (meaning "do better" rather than "hurry up")
- Get a move on.
- Get your finger out.
- Move it.
- Put your foot on it.
- Give it some welly.
- Hurry up.
- Take off the hand brake.
- Make tracks.
- Shake a leg.
- Scoot. (get away from here/me)
- Make tracks.
- Step on the gas/pedal/accelerator.
- Skedaddle.
- Get on with it.
- Put your back/heart into it.
- Make an effort.
- Do it like you mean it.

That should give you a few to think about.

Comment: get your finger out?? Never heard that...

Comment: It's reputed to have a colourful origin in the trenches in WWI.

Comment: This answer, by the way, was in answer to the OP's original question, not to their revised question, which is COMPLETELY different.

Comment: @Lambie - 'get your finger out' has been pretty familiar to me since childhood. In the 1960s, Prince Philip, when accompanying the Queen at the opening of a new road tunnel, is supposed to have said 'Is this the underpass from which we are to extract the digit?'

Comment: @Jaime - the colour would be brown, I guess.